# Add data stream on MP4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, data-stream

Im interesting to add some data on MP4 container, each time interval (similar to subtitle).
Is there any standard or open source that I can use?

Comment: What data do you wish to store?

Comment: just JSON text, e.g.{"id":"0_et201h0y_1_313","objectType":"objectType","timestamp":1.467893469759E12}